# How to have multiple lines in a treeItem in a treeView in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, treeview, scenebuilder

I was creating like a forum with javaFX. And the question and it's answers are formed using a treeView. Like the question would be a root and it's answers would be it's nodes.
But, it's happening that the treeItems are going straight in only one line, creating a horizontal scroll, and after some words, just putting '...' instead of the rest of the answers. I am using scene builder. Can anyone please tell me a way so that I can eliminate the horizontal scroll, and have the answer in multiple lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the cell's [WrapText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setWrapText-boolean-) property, e.g. in the column's cell factory.

Some answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732013/javafx-tablecolumn-text-wrapping) indicate that you have to bind the `wrappingWidthProperty` to a certain length if you use custom controls inside your cell.